# Objective-C: block enumeration for array in REVERSE order?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, objective-c-blocks

There is the `enumerateWithBlock` method of NSArray, but I need to enumerate in a reverse order, is there a block for doing that, or do I have to use `for` loop instead, not even the fast loop, but the traditional `for (int i = array.count - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)` one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock: passing  NSEnumerationReverse as the options parameter.

Comment: Is there any option for limit the loop to a maximum number? Say if I have 100 elements and I only want to loop through the last N?

Comment: @hzxu, There's no option to do that, but in the block, you have the idx property and the BOOL *stop, so you could set *stop to YES after you reach a certain index value.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `reverseObjectEnumerator`

```
for (id someObject in [myArray reverseObjectEnumerator])
{
    // print some info
    NSLog([someObject description]);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it is still using for loop without block, but maybe this is the only other solution